# HeaderCheckbox in datagridview strange behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have got a header checkbox for SelectAll in my checkboxColumn of my datagridview

```
    private void AddSelectAllCheckBox(DataGridView theDataGridView)
    {
        CheckBox cbx = new CheckBox();
        cbx.Name = "SelectAll";
        //The box size
        cbx.Size = new Size(14, 14);

        Rectangle rect = default(Rectangle);
        rect = theDataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true);
        //Put CheckBox in the middle-center of the column header.
        cbx.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(rect.Location.X + ((rect.Width - cbx.Width) / 2), rect.Location.Y + ((rect.Height - cbx.Height) / 2));
        cbx.BackColor = Color.White;
        theDataGridView.Controls.Add(cbx);

        //Handle header CheckBox check/uncheck function
        cbx.Click += HeaderCheckBox_Click;
        //When any CheckBox value in the DataGridViewRows changed,
        //check/uncheck the header CheckBox accordingly.
        //theDataGridView.CellValueChanged += DataGridView_CellChecked;
        //This event handler is necessary to commit new CheckBox cell value right after
        //user clicks the CheckBox.
        //Without it, CellValueChanged event occurs until the CheckBox cell lose focus
        //which means the header CheckBox won't display corresponding checked state instantly when user
        //clicks any one of the CheckBoxes.
        theDataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += DataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged;
    }

    private void HeaderCheckBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this._IsSelectAllChecked = true;

        CheckBox cbx = default(CheckBox);
        cbx = (CheckBox)sender;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in metroGrid1.Rows)
        {

            row.Cells[0].Value = cbx.Checked;

        }

        metroGrid1.EndEdit();

        this._IsSelectAllChecked = false;
    }



    //The CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event happens after user change the cell value,
    //before the cell lose focus and CellValueChanged event.
    private void DataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (dataGridView.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
        {
            //When the value changed cell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell, commit the change
            //to invoke the CellValueChanged event.
            dataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
    }
```

This is working fine.

If I check or uncheck the Checkbox in its row this event is fired and works:

```
        private void metroGrid1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex > -1)
        {
            //listBox1.Items.Add(" -> ");
            DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
            if (dgv == null)
                return;
            //if (dgv.CurrentRow)
            //{
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[Sel.Name].Value) == true)
                {
                    int selCount = Int32.Parse(metroLabel5.Text);
                    int addCount = selCount + Int32.Parse(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[Jobs.Name].Value.ToString());
                    metroLabel5.Text = addCount.ToString();
                    //listBox1.Items.Add(dgv.CurrentRow.Index.ToString() + " -> " + dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[Jobs.Name].Value.ToString());

                }
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[Sel.Name].Value) == false)
                {
                    int selCount = Int32.Parse(metroLabel5.Text);
                    int minCount = selCount - Int32.Parse(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[Jobs.Name].Value.ToString());
                    metroLabel5.Text = minCount.ToString();
                   // listBox1.Items.Add(dgv.CurrentRow.Index.ToString() + " -> " + dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[Jobs.Name].Value.ToString());
                }
            //}
        }
    }

    private void metroGrid1_OnCellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex > -1)
        {
            metroGrid1.EndEdit();
        }
    }
```

My problem:
If I check or uncheck the headerCheckbox the CellValueChanged Event is fired for each row which is ok, but it always uses the first row for the event.

For Example: I have 8 rows with jobs 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 so the metrolabel1.text should be 36 if all are selected, but with the selectAll checkbox it goes to 8 (8 time row 0 with 1 jobs)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Convert.ToBoolean(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[Sel.Name].Value)`
and `Int32.Parse(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[Jobs.Name].Value.ToString())`

The event fires for each cell that belongs to different row, so when you want to get a value from that row, you should refer to the row which event have been fired for:

```
dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column Name"].Value
```

Now in your code, you are getting the value for dgv.CurrentRow. This is not what you need.

Comment: Hi, the first suggestions did the trick, what do you mean with the second one ? where do i have this to implement ?

Comment: One more thing is strange, if I hit the SelectAll Checkbox all boxes are checked but one is not (it seems to be checked because the value is changed but the box is not shown es checked) it gets checked if I hit other controls in the form, a button or a comboBox.

Comment: This happend for the Checkbox if its cell is selected, if I leave this cell the checked icon is shown.

Comment: @user1073472 The first one is the exact fix you should do, the second one is the rule of those fix. `dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[Sel.Name].Value` and `dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[Jobs.Name].Value` both follow this rule `dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column Name"].Value`

Comment: @user1073472 for your other question, maybe a refreshing grid after checking header solve the problem. if Refresh didn't solve the problem it's better to ask a new question, this way it will be more helpful for others too.